# Find patterns and rename multiple files

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop, awk

I have a list of machine names and hostnames

ex)

```
# cat /tmp/machine_list.txt

[one]apple machine #1  myserver1
[two]apple machine #2  myserver2
[three]apple machine #3  myserver3
```

and, server each directory
and each directory contains an tar file and a file with the host name written on it.

```
# ls  /tmp/sos1/*
sosreport1.tar.gz
hostname_map.txt

# cat /tmp/sos1/hostname_map.txt 
myserver1


# ls  /tmp/sos2/*
sosreport2.tar.gz
hostname_map.txt

# cat /tmp/sos2/hostname_map.txt 
myserver2


# ls  /tmp/sos3/*
sosreport3.tar.gz
hostname_map.txt

# cat /tmp/sos3/hostname_map.txt 
myserver3
```

Is it possible to rename the sosreport*.tar.gz by referencing the hostname_map in each directory relative to the /tmp/machine_list.txt file? (like below)

```
# ls  /tmp/sos1/*
[one]apple_machine_#1_myserver1_sosreport1.tar.gz

# ls  /tmp/sos2/*
[two]apple_machine_#2_myserver2_sosreport2.tar.gz

# ls  /tmp/sos3/*
[three]apple_machine_#3_myserver3_sosreport3.tar.gz
```

A single change is possible, but what about multiple changes?

Comment: It's not totally clear how your `hostname_map.txt` and `machine_list.txt` are related. Also, what is the current directory? You have `ls -l /tmp/…` and then `cat ./…`. How is the final format computed? Collapse all blanks into a single blank and then replace them with an underscore?

Comment: Hi knittl , edited according to your guide..  yes, all blanks are replaced with underscore. machine_list.txt refers to the information in hostname_map.txt ( machine name and hsotname) and finally changes the file name of sosreport *.tar.gz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
srvname () {
    awk -v srv="$(cat "$1")" -F '\t' '$2==srv { print $1; exit }' machine_list.txt
}
 
for dir in /tmp/sos*/; do
    server=$(srvname "$dir"/hostname_map.txt)
    mv "$dir"/sosreport*.tar.gz "$dir/$server.tar.gz"
done
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/TS5VyQ

The function assumes your mapping file is tab-delimited. If you want underscores instead of spaces in the server names, change the mapping file.

This should be portable to POSIX `sh`; the `cat` could be replaced with a Bash redirection, but I feel that it's not worth giving up portability for such a small change.

If this were my project, I'd probably make the function into a self-contained reusable script (with the input file replaced with a here document in the script itself) since there will probably be more situations where you need to perform the same mapping.